# Object removed from assembly still referred to after deploy to Azure, local is fine

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, deployment, build, azure-devops

ASP.NET Core 2.1

We have a shared dll, that is used in a few projects (via project reference)

We have class in that was named `Proofer`, and is now named `ProofReader`.
This was done through mass find and replace.

Nowhere in our source files locally exists any files containing the text `Proofer`.

VSTS builds the application without issue, then we send it via a release pipeline to Azure. All succeed.

Despite this we attempt to run the web app and get the following:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> TypeLoadException: Could not load type
> 'MainShared.Models.Proofer' from assembly 'MainShared,
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
>
> System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule
> pModule, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob,
> Int32* pcNamedArgs)

We are having trouble determining if this is in the build, maybe something not being rebuilt when it should be, or something still cached on Azure that isn't being overwritten.

Comment: Have you check the reference of your projects? I think one of the project still reference it?

Comment: The references have not changed, the class Proofer was in the same project that ProofReader was in.

Comment: Also, we checked all the csproj files for the word Proofer. None found

Comment: are you  deploying your app in an app service(PAAS) or Virtual Machine(IAAS)  ?

Comment: We are using an app service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few places I can suggest you look into -

1. If you are using app service web apps in azure , we can use the kudu (web app extension to remove/clean the files) to make sure you have a clean destination.
2. Check the VSTS Release logs if you have access to , it shows the files which are overwritten and the ones which could not be. Once i had a similar issue and found that the logs were already warning me that a few could not be overwritten.
3. If you are  using VM's  for your app deployment if has access to it , remove/backup the files under your site  folder.

Comment: We are working. there was a file .\MainApp.PrecompiledViews.dll for some reason was out of date, and still referring still to Proofer. We renamed it, and all is working now. Your comment about using kudu was super helpful, as there are so many tools there we can now use.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after some redesign for a Web App using ASP.NET Core 2.2 (hosted on Azure), that some old not even anymore existing references causing the Load type exceptions to happen and the Web App simply refused to come up. I tried to clean everything up in Visual Studio, even deleted the bin and object directories, but the old reference was still looked for. In Kudu on the Azure portal I saw the *.PrecompiledViews.dll and *.PrecompiledViews.pdb files, which were very old. I simply removed them directly on the Azure server and could then simply start up my app and everything came up again. This fault should be fixed from the source. If I do a complete rebuild, I expect this old garbage to be taken care of during the publishing to the website. This is something that Microsoft should fix and as I can see this happened to others over half a year ago. Thanks Mark Johnson for your very useful hint about those files!